# CSV file - Combine title if value=YES in another cell - Libreoffice / Excel / Googledocs

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, libreoffice-calc, google-docs

I have a file with text divided into cells that I want to group into another cell.
Cells are:

[image]

*A, B, C,* and *D* are what I have. In each coluimn, if the value is Yes, I would like the *Result* column to display the title of each Yes. So for the first one, as an example, Blue**COMMA** Green**COMMA** Yellow**DOT**
Is this possible to achieve? If so, how?
Thank you.

Edit: 2016 office without 365 subscription doesn't have textjoin. Looking for a LibreOffice / Googledocs answer.

Comment: there is no built-in formula for that, however there is already an answer for your question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639868/vba-user-defined-function-for-concatenate-if-by-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TEXTJOIN` for this if you have Excel 2016 and a 365 subscriber.

In F2 use the below, and drag down:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(A2:D2="yes",$A$1:$D$1,""))}
```

Enter this as an array using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

**If you don't have 365 subscription**, you can use a long winded IF statement, again enter in F2 and drag down:

`=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IF(A2="yes",$A$1,"")&" "&IF(B2="yes",$B$1,"")&" "&IF(C2="yes",$C$1,"")&" "&IF(D2="yes",$D$1,""))," ",", ")`

**For Google Docs Use:**

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A2:D2="Yes",A$1:D$1,))&".")
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be the way to go. I do have office 2016, however I don't have the text join function. Is there a way to add this? I found a post saying that only 365 subscribers get it...

Comment: It seems LibreOffice may have it, I'm gonna give it a shot.

Comment: I didn't realize TEXTJOIN was only available to 365 subscribers, that's pretty crappy of MS. I have an update for my answer you can use anyway @riseagainst

Comment: That would also work, but my example is very simplified, I have some 40+ columns. I think libreoffice will work, I just can't get the syntax right.

Comment: Have you tested this on excel? I can't get it to work on libreoffice or google docs.

Comment: if you want to update your answer to includes this for google docs, I'll mark it as accepted, this works: =ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A2:D2="Yes",A$1:D$1,))&".")

Comment: @riseagainst added it